# Produce Manual beep sound from Magellan 9800i scanner scale device using Microsoft Point of Services in C#

Tags: scale, barcode-scanner, pos, beep

Hello everyone here I'm stuck in this issue can you please help me out from this. 
Here I'm using this device and I want to **generate a beep sound manually** from **Magellan 9800i scanner/scale** device.
I used Microsoft Point of Service to integrate this hardware device in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The tone and bell commands are listed in Appendix D, Host Commands, in the [Magellan 9800i Product Reference Guide](https://www.eptechnologyinc.com/wp-content/uploads/820048614.pdf).
One of 0x42,0x01,0x07.

```
Beep Good Read Tone  'B' 0x42  
Force Good Read Tone     0x01  
Bel                      0x07
```

The [Datalogic OPOS Service Objects User Manual](https://www.datalogic.com/upload/marketlit/manuals/opos/820025614.pdf) page 35, 41 states that `DR90000351 Datalogic UPOS DirectIO Commands` has a complete list of DirectIO methods and implementation details.

Please contact Datalogic support to see if you can send those host commands using the DirectIO method.

Comment: He seems to be stuck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888981/how-i-can-implement-directio-event-of-pos-scanner-using-c-net